# Is there a way to secure a live agent deployment?

Tags: liveagent, pre-chat

I am working on putting a liveAgent deployment in our website, I basically got a javascript snippet like the one shared here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_deployment_api_code_sample.htm

But I am afraid that if someone gets our snippet (A bad actor within our customers could just copy the snippet from the browser), he/she could initiate a chat and made our Agents think he/she is one of our Customers.

I tried restricting the domains where our Chat can be deploy but still I modified my local /etc/hosts and was able to initiate a chat.

I was wondering if there is a way of putting a digital signature out of the "customDetails" or get a unique token/sessionid on the backend prior to initiate the liveagent on the frontend...

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't that same bad actor just take the same actions from wherever the chat button is hosted? Or is it authenticated?

Comment: It is authenticated. Actually, not all our users can see the chat button. We want to make sure that the chat can be initiated only from our website. 

We pass some custom details from the logged in user profile, like name, email, companyId (ours is a multi-tenant app)...